# How can I know the progress when importing data into MySQL using LOAD DATA INFILE?

Tags: mysql

I have a 1 billion record stored in csv file. I'm using `LOAD DATA INFILE` to import the record to the table.

```
create table weibo_bind
(
    column1 bigint
        primary key,
    column2 bigint
);
```

And my csv file is `column1,column2`.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/demo.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE weibo_bind FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

But how can I debug or how can I check the progress of importing? Because it takes a lot of time to import.

Or is there any way to speed up?

I'm using

mysql  Ver 8.0.22, Innodb

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using? Is the table innodb? If so ensure large innodb buffer pool size and a large innodb log file size (~1G). With MariaDB `SHOW PROCESSLIST` will show the [progress](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/progress-reporting/).

Comment: If you want to check from external application then you may obtain approximate information by checking table's .IBD file size.

Comment: @danblack `SHOW PROCESSLIST` shows the command which is executing, but still no progress information.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for your information, I checked my `.IBD` , the file becomes much large then the origin one. So I am still confused about how many records have been imported.

Comment: *the file becomes much large then the origin one* This is a norma. Moreover, the final size will depend on rows order in source file for the same data array, on the data present and the amount of not used space caused by delete/truncate in a table before importing.. that's why I tell that the info is approximate. *the file becomes much large then the origin one.* I think that the difference is not more than ~30%.. if it is more than the rows order in your file is very unfortunate.

Comment: Origin file is 17GB, and now the IBD file is now 26G, still cannot know when is the end.

Comment: Finally, it takes 8000 seconds to finish, and 17 GB text file becomes 32G table.

Comment: Also look at configuring [IO capacity](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-configuring-io-capacity.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sort the incoming file by the `PRIMARY KEY`; this will speed up the `LOAD`.  Don't have any secondary keys during the load.

There is no way (that I know of) to watch the progress in 8.0.

The `.ibd` file size is not a reliable indication -- you can't easily predict how big it will eventually be.  Datatypes, data values, PK, other indexes, etc, impact the size.

Also, that file will grow in bursts.

Having just two BIGINTs (8 bytes each), the table might be about 40-60 bytes per row.  The smaller range might be about right if the data is in PK order; the larger if not.

I hope the query does not timeout.

The process is probably I/O-bound, indicating that nothing you could do would speed it up.